# Compile-time version comparison in D

Tags: version, d, compile-time

I want *compile-time* (because to be used in `static if`) comparison of version strings in D.

For example `1.2.12` is greater than `1.2.2`. I want to do such comparisons compile-time.

Comment: Do you have a function that can do that comparison at normal runtime?

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe No, I don't yet have a function (neither for compile time nor for runtime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a function that works at runtime. Then call it. Something like:

```
bool less(string a, string b)
{
  auto ap = a.splitter(".").map!(x => to!int(x));
  auto bp = b.splitter(".").map!(x => to!int(x));
  while (!ap.empty && !bp.empty)
  {
    if (ap.front < bp.front) return true;
    ap.popFront; bp.popFront;
  }
  return ap.empty;
}
static if (less("1.2.12", "1.2.2"))
  pragma(msg, "it's less");
else
  pragma(msg, "it's not less");
```

You can call normal functions at compile time.  This is what in D we call CTFE (compile time function evaluation).

To quote Walter Bright (from my memory) "D has the unique ability to run D code at compile time".

Comment: Thanks, but now I understand that it's nearly useless, because I can't pass strings to the compiler (except of by using `-J` or by generating a `.d` file). I will better define versions like Raptor_0_2_15 to mean that the version of Raptor is at least `0.2.15`. It's ugly but seems the best solution.

Comment: I've changed my mind, your code is useful. I am going to use a generated `config.d` file for configuraion settings